# Spring security core and spring security crypto maven artifacts (duplicate classes)

Tags: spring-security

I'm building a self-contained jar with the maven shade plugin (an uberjar) and I get warnings for all the spring-security-crypto classes:

```
[WARNING] We have a duplicate org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.class in ***\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
[WARNING] We have a duplicate org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.class in ***\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
[WARNING] We have a duplicate org/springframework/security/crypto/codec/Base64.class in ***\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
[WARNING] We have a duplicate org/springframework/security/crypto/codec/Hex.class in ***\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
[WARNING] We have a duplicate org/springframework/security/crypto/codec/InvalidBase64CharacterException.class in ***\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
[WARNING] We have a duplicate org/springframework/security/crypto/codec/package-info.class in ***\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
[WARNING] We have a duplicate org/springframework/security/crypto/codec/Utf8.class in ***\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
[WARNING] We have a duplicate org/springframework/security/crypto/encrypt/AesBytesEncryptor$1.class in ***\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
[WARNING] We have a duplicate org/springframework/security/crypto/encrypt/AesBytesEncryptor.class in ***\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
...
```

I looked into the spring-security-core jar and saw that it contains all the classes spring-security-crypto contains. Furthermore upon comparing the sources you see they are the same.

I know I can ignore it since the classes are the same but:

1. This can change if the classes in spring-security-core don't get updated.
2. More importantly I don't understand why this is happening? It is important to note that spring-security-core itself has a compile dependency on spring-security-crypto which totally baffles me.

Would love any explanation and solution that are out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [a bug in 3.1.0](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1907). There shouldn't be dependency from core to crypto. The separate crypto jar is only intended for use in some other Spring projects which don't use Spring Security. It's a side-effect of the way the build is configured that it ended up in the core pom.

Just add a [Maven exclusion](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) to your pom dependency for `spring-security-core` to stop it pulling in the crpyto jar as a transitive dependency.